# Is my command to clone a drive optimal?

Tags: dd

I have done half an hour reading around to prepare to clone my hard drive.  It has multiple partitions, including a Windows partition.  I am going to buy a very large external hard drive for the backup.  I would like to be able to use this clone to restore the whole drive in case something goes wrong (I'm about to do some OS re-shuffling).  I want do learn how to do this using dd, as I like low-level tools that don't require installing anything.

I found the following useful code from the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5627660&postcount=14) (entered from a root shell using a live CD):

```
dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/hdb & pid=$!
while kill -USR1 $pid; do sleep 1; done
```

(I know that I will have to edit the input and output locations.)  However I have two questions.  The first one is very noobie: this command is split across two lines.  Surely when I press enter after the exclamation mark it will start the process?

Two, on other sites it recommended entering block size.  Like this:

```
# dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K of=/mnt/sda1/hda.img
```

I don't know anything about block sizes.  Is 64K right?  It looks like my block size is 512 bytes from the following, the output of sudo fdisk -ul:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3ffc3ff

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   143364059    71681998+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2       976867328  1465147391   244140032    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       143364094   976867327   416751617    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       143364096   162895871     9765888   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       162897920   205864959    21483520   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       205867008   976867327   385500160   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 10.0 GB, 10000269312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1215 cylinders, total 19531776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x433bb3a7

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `dd if=/dev/hda of=hdb`?   Here is an answer that shows some details including runtime for 160 GB:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/435694/can-i-dd-a-larger-drive-to-a-smaller-one/936556#936556

Comment: Recent versions of Ubuntu utilize coreutils v.8.24 or later in which `dd` includes a progress switch as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/685766/225694)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Progress

The command you listed

```
dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/hdb & pid=$!
while kill -USR1 $pid; do sleep 1; done
```

is a nice two-liner to get the the progress of `dd` on a regular basis. I use a very similar one too. Looks good. Found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/110513/88802) perhaps?

#### Blocksizes with `dd`: alignment and performance

You can add a block size in which the operations take place. It does not matter what the block size of the underlying block device is to get the operation done equally well, but for performance reasons you might want to pick one that suits your needs.

First of all, there's [the alignment thing](https://askubuntu.com/a/243947/88802). In case your block device operates as 512KiB (like flash drives do), it would be very unfortunate to run `dd` with `bs=512` (bytes) as this will cause 1024 writes (!) for each block from the device perspective. In practise it won't be this bad as writes are buffered and taken into one go, but during syncs it can still *amplify* the amount of writes a lot.

Then also consider the plain CPU usage overhead when dealing with a very large amount of small operations. It's just more efficient to take megabytes at once when copying over large amounts of data.

My best practice is to start with 1MB as that is a nice multiple of most set ups, including RAID stripe sizes, LVM extent sizes, etc. On my laptop with SSD I tend to see a slight improvement using 10MB as block size, whereas I don't see it anymore on my physical hard drive.

#### Last block

Don't worry about the drive/volume size not being a multiple of the block size. The last block `dd` will copy will be adjusted to match the last bit of data on it. You can see whether the last block had a different size by looking at the output.

```
18335302+0 records out
```

The `+0` means that it was an exact match, a `+1` means that it wasn't. No big deal.

#### See also

- [Good block size for disk cloning with diskdump (dd)](https://superuser.com/a/234241/157409)

Comment: Wow, what a thorough answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to do it. I will updat the original question with a link to my source.  I will go with 1 MB then. So my command will be like this, am I right?

`# dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=1MB of=/mnt/sda1/hda.img & pid=$!`
`while kill -USR1 $pid; do sleep 1; done`

Comment: @oldmankit I'd do `bs=1M` as that's a power of 2, rather than `bs=1MB` being a power of 10. But just run some benchmarks on your system if you can to see what's the best.

Comment: Note that as mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd) since the release of coreutils >= 8.24 (default in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 upwards) it's no longer necessary to `kill -USR1 $pid` dd now has a progress report available by adding the `status=progress` switch

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, there is no universally correct block size; what is optimal for one situation or one piece of hardware may be terribly inefficient for another. Also, depending on the health of the disks it may be preferable to use a different block size than what is "optimal".

One thing that is pretty reliable on modern hardware is that the default block size of 512 bytes tends to be almost an order of magnitude slower than a more optimal alternative. When in doubt, I've found that 64K is a pretty solid modern default. Though 64K usually isn't THE optimal block size, in my experience it tends to be a lot more efficient than the default. 64K also has a pretty solid history of being reliably performant: You can find [a message from the Eug-Lug mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/eug-lug@efn.org/msg12073.html), circa 2002, recommending a block size of 64K.

For determining THE optimal output block size, I've written the following script that tests writing a 128M test file with dd at a range of different block sizes, from the default of 512 bytes to a maximum of 64M. Be warned, this script uses dd internally, so use with caution.

`dd_obs_test.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Since we're dealing with dd, abort if any errors occur
set -e

TEST_FILE=${1:-dd_obs_testfile}
TEST_FILE_EXISTS=0
if [ -e "$TEST_FILE" ]; then TEST_FILE_EXISTS=1; fi
TEST_FILE_SIZE=134217728

if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "NOTE: Kernel cache will not be cleared between tests without sudo. This will likely cause inaccurate results." 1>&2
fi

# Header
PRINTF_FORMAT="%8s : %s\n"
printf "$PRINTF_FORMAT" 'block size' 'transfer rate'

# Block sizes of 512b 1K 2K 4K 8K 16K 32K 64K 128K 256K 512K 1M 2M 4M 8M 16M 32M 64M
for BLOCK_SIZE in 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864
do
  # Calculate number of segments required to copy
  COUNT=$(($TEST_FILE_SIZE / $BLOCK_SIZE))

  if [ $COUNT -le 0 ]; then
    echo "Block size of $BLOCK_SIZE estimated to require $COUNT blocks, aborting further tests."
    break
  fi

  # Clear kernel cache to ensure more accurate test
  [ $EUID -eq 0 ] && [ -e /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ] && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

  # Create a test file with the specified block size
  DD_RESULT=$(dd if=/dev/zero of=$TEST_FILE bs=$BLOCK_SIZE count=$COUNT conv=fsync 2>&1 1>/dev/null)

  # Extract the transfer rate from dd's STDERR output
  TRANSFER_RATE=$(echo $DD_RESULT | \grep --only-matching -E '[0-9.]+ ([MGk]?B|bytes)/s(ec)?')

  # Clean up the test file if we created one
  if [ $TEST_FILE_EXISTS -ne 0 ]; then rm $TEST_FILE; fi

  # Output the result
  printf "$PRINTF_FORMAT" "$BLOCK_SIZE" "$TRANSFER_RATE"
done
```

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/tdg5/blog/blob/master/_includes/scripts/dd_obs_test.sh)

I've only tested this script on a Debian (Ubuntu) system and on OSX Yosemite, so it will probably take some tweaking to make work on other Unix flavors.

By default the command will create a test file named `dd_obs_testfile` in the current directory. Alternatively, you can provide a path to a custom test file by providing a path after the script name:

```
$ ./dd_obs_test.sh /path/to/disk/test_file
```

The output of the script is a list of the tested block sizes and their respective transfer
rates like so:

```
$ ./dd_obs_test.sh
block size : transfer rate
       512 : 11.3 MB/s
      1024 : 22.1 MB/s
      2048 : 42.3 MB/s
      4096 : 75.2 MB/s
      8192 : 90.7 MB/s
     16384 : 101 MB/s
     32768 : 104 MB/s
     65536 : 108 MB/s
    131072 : 113 MB/s
    262144 : 112 MB/s
    524288 : 133 MB/s
   1048576 : 125 MB/s
   2097152 : 113 MB/s
   4194304 : 106 MB/s
   8388608 : 107 MB/s
  16777216 : 110 MB/s
  33554432 : 119 MB/s
  67108864 : 134 MB/s
```

(Note: The unit of the transfer rates will vary by OS)

To test optimal read block size, you could use more or less the same process,
but instead of reading from `/dev/zero` and writing to the disk, you'd read from
the disk and write to `/dev/null`. A script to do this might look like so:

`dd_ibs_test.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Since we're dealing with dd, abort if any errors occur
set -e

TEST_FILE=${1:-dd_ibs_testfile}
if [ -e "$TEST_FILE" ]; then TEST_FILE_EXISTS=$?; fi
TEST_FILE_SIZE=134217728

# Exit if file exists
if [ -e $TEST_FILE ]; then
  echo "Test file $TEST_FILE exists, aborting."
  exit 1
fi
TEST_FILE_EXISTS=1

if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "NOTE: Kernel cache will not be cleared between tests without sudo. This will likely cause inaccurate results." 1>&2
fi

# Create test file
echo 'Generating test file...'
BLOCK_SIZE=65536
COUNT=$(($TEST_FILE_SIZE / $BLOCK_SIZE))
dd if=/dev/urandom of=$TEST_FILE bs=$BLOCK_SIZE count=$COUNT conv=fsync > /dev/null 2>&1

# Header
PRINTF_FORMAT="%8s : %s\n"
printf "$PRINTF_FORMAT" 'block size' 'transfer rate'

# Block sizes of 512b 1K 2K 4K 8K 16K 32K 64K 128K 256K 512K 1M 2M 4M 8M 16M 32M 64M
for BLOCK_SIZE in 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864
do
  # Clear kernel cache to ensure more accurate test
  [ $EUID -eq 0 ] && [ -e /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ] && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

  # Read test file out to /dev/null with specified block size
  DD_RESULT=$(dd if=$TEST_FILE of=/dev/null bs=$BLOCK_SIZE 2>&1 1>/dev/null)

  # Extract transfer rate
  TRANSFER_RATE=$(echo $DD_RESULT | \grep --only-matching -E '[0-9.]+ ([MGk]?B|bytes)/s(ec)?')

  printf "$PRINTF_FORMAT" "$BLOCK_SIZE" "$TRANSFER_RATE"
done

# Clean up the test file if we created one
if [ $TEST_FILE_EXISTS -ne 0 ]; then rm $TEST_FILE; fi
```

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/tdg5/blog/blob/master/_includes/scripts/dd_ibs_test.sh)

An important difference in this case is that the test file is a file that is written by the script. Do not point this command at an existing file or the existing file will be overwritten with random data!

For my particular hardware I found that 128K was the most optimal input block size on a HDD and 32K was most optimal on a SSD.

Though this answer covers most of my findings, I've needed to determine an optimal dd block size enough times that I wrote [a blog post](http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/) about it. You can find more specifics on the tests I performed there.

This StackOverflow post may also be useful: [dd: How to calculate optimal blocksize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161823/dd-how-to-calculate-optimal-blocksize/27772496)

Comment: Teach a man to fish = +1

Comment: @tdg5 This is a great script, but it runs into fatal errors when executed from within Cygwin on a Windows 7 environment. Is there a version of it that will work on Cygwin?