# Is sudo dd taking too long to wipe hard drive?

Tags: sudo, dd

I have a 200gb HDD which I removed from a macbook due to several corrupt files in startup. One thing led to another and I decided that I needed to format the drive.

I used the command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

which is supposed to wipe everything off of the hard drive. It is my understanding that the command writes 0's over every bit on the drive, which I would imagine must take a while. The process has been going for about 18 hours now. I can use other functions of operating system like the web browser and I can even use another terminal window, so I know the system is not frozen.

Should I restart the process or let it continue on?

Any advice will help. Thanks.

By the way, I already noticed a post similar to this that was previously answered though the user was not using the same command as I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You command is writing to the disk using 512 Byte blocks which is quite slow as it needs a lot of blocks. You can increase the block size using the `bs=N` parameter.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246921/is-my-command-to-clone-a-drive-optimal#246960) for a short explanation and [this question at Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/234199/good-block-size-for-disk-cloning-with-diskdump-dd/) for what block size  to choose.

Comment: Oh alright that makes sense, thanks for the response. Do you think is it worth resetting the process with a longer Byte size after it has been running for this long?